# I want to write a SQL Query that will determine the company having highest no .of employees, & then display it's employees with previous company

Tags: mysql, sql, join, logic, case

I have a schema that has following two tables

**1. People** -

```
+-------+----------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| ID    | NAME           | DOJ        | PREV_COMPANY_ID | CURR_COMPANY_ID |
+-------+----------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1795f | ALEX BROWN     | 1973-03-02 | 4e5b            | 123a            |
| 8772  | Chris Mitchell | 2016-06-15 | 4746            | 4e5b            |
| 5e03  | Patt Hobbs     | 1976-09-14 | 4e5b            | 123b            |
+-------+----------------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

**2. Company -**

```
+-------+---------------+
| ID    | NAME          |
+-------+---------------+
| 4746  | Mora-Sullivan |
| 49de6 | Harmon-Miller |
| 4e5b  | Fakesmith     |
+-------+---------------+
```

I want to write the query to find the following -

1. First Determine the Company/Companies that has highest no.of employees & then display it's employees with previous company.

I have found out the company which has the highest employees using sql query. i.e Fakesmith here.

```
SELECT PREV_COMPANY_ID, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM PEOPLE 
GROUP BY PREV_COMPANY_ID
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

But I am unable to buildup any logic to find, the current employers of the highest number of employees with their previous company names. How can I solve this query?

Comment: I want only one max value record as test case here can only have one value record.

Comment: @AlexandreLéonard No, It should be PREV_COMPANY_ID as we want to determine highest number of employees from prev_company_id and then check in curr_company_id for employees working in that company and then display their names with previous_company.
Also your query returns error code 1241 Operand Should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying something like this:

```
create table people(
id varchar(9) not null ,
name varchar(50) not null ,
doj date ,
PREV_COMPANY_ID varchar(50),
CURR_COMPANY_ID varchar(50),
Primary key id(`id`)
);

insert into people values ('1795f','ALEX BROWN','1973-03-02','4e5b','123a'),('8772','Chris Mitchell','2016-06-15','4746','4e5b'),('5e03','Patt Hobbs','1976-09-14','4e5b','123b');


create table company(
id varchar(9) not null ,
name varchar(50) not null ,
Primary key id(`id`)
);

insert into company values ('4746','Mora-Sullivan'),('49de6','Harmon-Miller'),('4e5b','Fakesmith');


select p.name,p.CURR_COMPANY_ID,company.name as company_name 
from people p join (select PREV_COMPANY_ID ,count(*) as comp_high_nr from people group by PREV_COMPANY_ID  order by comp_high_nr desc limit 1) as t on p.CURR_COMPANY_ID =t.PREV_COMPANY_ID join company on p.PREV_COMPANY_ID=company.id  ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if following query serve your purpose

```
SELECT *
  FROM PEOPLE
 WHERE CURR_COMPANY_ID IN (  SELECT PREV_COMPANY_ID
                               FROM (  SELECT PREV_COMPANY_ID, COUNT (1) AS C
                                         FROM PEOPLE
                                     GROUP BY CURR_COMPANY_ID
                                     ORDER BY C DESC)
                           ORDER BY c DESC)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to display the current comapny name of the Chris Mitchell so how can I do it?, I know it can be done using join but any idea how can I implement it in this code you have provided?

Comment: try this  SELECT * ,(select name from company where id=CURR_COMPANY_ID)
  FROM PEOPLE 
 WHERE CURR_COMPANY_ID IN (  SELECT PREV_COMPANY_ID
                               FROM (  SELECT PREV_COMPANY_ID, COUNT (1) AS C
                                         FROM PEOPLE
                                     GROUP BY CURR_COMPANY_ID
                                     ORDER BY C DESC)
                           ORDER BY c DESC) ;

Answer (score 0):

Try this one will help you

```
CREATE TABLE tblcompany (
  id varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO tblcompany (id,name) VALUES 
 ('1','Mora-Sullivan'),
 ('2','Harmon-Miller'),
 ('3','Fakesmith');

CREATE TABLE tblpeople (
  id varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  doj date DEFAULT NULL,
  PREV_COMPANY_ID varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  CURR_COMPANY_ID varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO tblpeople (id,name,doj,PREV_COMPANY_ID,CURR_COMPANY_ID) VALUES 
 ('1','ALEX BROWN','1973-03-02','1','2'),
 ('2','Chris Mitchell','2016-06-15','1','3'),
 ('3','Patt Hobbs','1976-09-14','2','3');
```

First, we need to get companies with the highest employee's

```
SELECT t1.CURR_COMPANY_ID, COUNT(t1.id) as `NoOfEmployee` FROM tblpeople as t1 GROUP BY t1.CURR_COMPANY_ID ORDER BY NoOfEmployee DESC LIMIT 1;
```

[image]

Then we join with people table to get all employees for that company

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.name as `CURR_COMPANY`, t3.name as `PREV_COMPANY` FROM tblpeople as t1 LEFT JOIN tblcompany as t2 ON t1.CURR_COMPANY_ID=t2.id LEFT JOIN tblcompany as t3 ON t1.PREV_COMPANY_ID=t3.id INNER JOIN (SELECT CURR_COMPANY_ID, COUNT(id) as EmployeeCount FROM tblpeople GROUP BY CURR_COMPANY_ID ORDER BY EmployeeCount DESC LIMIT 1) as t4 ON t1.CURR_COMPANY_ID=t4.CURR_COMPANY_ID;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's mysql:

```
SELECT people.Name, companies.Name
FROM people
JOIN companies ON people.PREV_COMPANY_ID = companies.ID
WHERE people.CURR_COMPANY_ID = (
SELECT companies.ID
FROM people
JOIN companies ON people.PREV_COMPANY_ID = companies.ID
GROUP BY companies.ID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY people.Name ASC;
```

Comment: Can you format the code in your answers using the triple back-tick's (one back tick -> `) so that the code is easier to read? 

```
example
```